# Meaning / usage of vertical bar in Practical Foundations for Programming Languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm working my way through [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf) but am finding some of the notation difficult to follow. In section 3.3 (page 46 of linked PDF) the author introduces a vertical bar notation that I imagine comes from somewhere in formal logic and I'm not sure how to interpret it.

> *Generic derivability* judgment is defined by:
>
> [image]
>
> *Parametric derivability* is defined by:
>
> [image]

How should the | and || symbols be understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That part of the text is *defining* what the vertical bars mean. You write that when the right hand side of the iff holds.